# R dataframe - how to add more rows as a subset

Tags: r

This question is similar to what has been asked, but I can't see to figure out how to apply it to my data.

I have a dataframe of 1875 rows. Now, in each row, there is a field `nbc` which is a large string. I then run a function (arbritrary, irrelevant) on it which returns certain substrings from `nbc`. Sometimes it will return 1 substring, sometimes 20. What I want to do is append this information to my dataframe.

So consider this

```
+----+-------+-------------+
| id |  seq  |     nbc     |
+----+-------+-------------+
|  1 | atcgg | atgccttatac |
|  2 | tatgc | tataggctata |
+----+-------+-------------+
```

taking the first, and applying my function on `nbc` I get the following 2 substrings: `atgc`, `tatac` which are of interest to me. I now want to append this to the dataframe like following:

```
+----+-------+-------------+------------+
| id |  seq  |     nbc     | substrings |
+----+-------+-------------+------------+
|  1 | atcgg | atgccttatac | atgc       |
|  1 | atcgg | atgccttatac | tatac      |
|  2 | tatgc | tataggctata |            |
+----+-------+-------------+------------+
```

So the row gets duplicated for each substring it finds..

Any ideas on how to do this efficiently? I just need pseduocode as I will be using the foreach/parallel package to parallelize it.

Comment: Do you want each substrings to generate a duplicate row ? Or would you prefer to have substrings = c("atgc", "tatac")

Comment: I don't see an alternative. This will be quite inefficient.

Comment: Why not return a (two or more) row dataframe by using the recycling property of `data.frame`? just give the function result or it's sapply( ..., fn) result if it's not vectorized as the third column value and all the other values will get replicated.

Comment: @masfenix It looks like your `seq` column is unrelated to everything else that's going on, is that correct?

Comment: For this purpose, yes. @StevenBeaupré That's exactly what I am trying to do right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, and if you are willing to use a `data.table` (at least as an intermediate step), you could do something like this:

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr) 
##
foo <- function(x,y) {
  res <- unlist(str_extract_all(x,y))
  if (length(res)>0) {
    res
  } else {
    ""
  }
}
##
Dt <- data.table(Df)
##
R>  Dt[,list(substrings=foo(
    x=nbc,
    y="atgc|tatac")),
    by="id,seq,nbc"]
   id   seq         nbc substrings
1:  1 atcgg atgccttatac       atgc
2:  1 atcgg atgccttatac      tatac
3:  2 tatgc tataggctata
```

assuming your desired substrings were either of `atgc` or `tatac` (I wasn't completely clear on that part). It's kind of hard do any rigorous testing on a 3 row `data.frame` / `data.table`, but this method seemed to work on a sample object I created (below), extracting substrings of 3 or more digits from random sequences of numbers and letters:

```
m <- replicate(
  5,
  paste(
    sample(
      c(letters[1:10],0:9),
      20,
      replace=TRUE),
    collapse=""))
m <- c(m,paste(letters[1:20],collapse=""))
##
R>  m
[1] "7j166a6b1a30hg1e8j05" "d1h6f634386ag41309i9" "egf98f8g5f60be345g3e"
[4] "7140447bjb4gj78f313d" "h1j9bij94b9dj28ed72d" "abcdefghijklmnopqrst"
##
DF <- data.frame(
  id=1:6,
  seq=sample(LETTERS,6),
  nbc=m,
  stringsAsFactors=F)
##
DT <- data.table(DF)
##
R>  DT[,list(sequences=foo(
    x=nbc,y="\\d{3,}")),
    by="id,seq,nbc"]
   id seq                  nbc sequences
1:  1   H 7j166a6b1a30hg1e8j05       166
2:  2   A d1h6f634386ag41309i9    634386
3:  2   A d1h6f634386ag41309i9     41309
4:  3   J egf98f8g5f60be345g3e       345
5:  4   G 7140447bjb4gj78f313d   7140447
6:  4   G 7140447bjb4gj78f313d       313
7:  5   C h1j9bij94b9dj28ed72d          
8:  6   L abcdefghijklmnopqrst
```

where the `seq` column is meaningless in the above object.

---

*Data for the first example:*

```
Df <- data.frame(
  id=1:2,
  seq=c("atcgg","tatgc"),
  nbc=c("atgccttatac","tataggctata"),
  stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd proceed as follow (hard to test, since you didn't provide a reproducible example):

```
 #apply myfunc to each element of nbc
 substrings<-lapply(df$nbc,myfunc)
 #get the length of each element of substrings
 lengths<-vapply(substrings,length,1L)
 #repeat each row of your data.frame as many times as the number of substrings returned by myfunc
 df<-df[rep(1:nrow(df),lengths),]
 #add the substrings column
 df$columns<-unlist(substrings)
```

Of course it isn't tested, but may work.